# Svg draw animation lead to page crash in chrome (Aw, Snap page)

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, keyframe

I made an SVG animation to draw path, I used the common stroke dashoffset technique:

```
.animate svg path {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke: #848484;
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: 7200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 7200;
    animation: draw 60s linear 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation: draw 60s linear 1 forwards;
}
```

and used @keyframes as following:

```
@keyframes draw {
   0% {
     stroke-dashoffset: -7200;
   }
   100%{
     stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
  }

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -7200;
  }
  100%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -7200;
   }

  100%{
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }

 }
```

I made the duration 60s because the SVG is a building graph with a lot of details (windows, etc.), so in order to get the cool drawing effect I had to make it in long duration to take its time while drawing the building outlines.

Don't worry visitors won't see it for 60 second :), drawing effect will be hidden by the real image after 4 seconds.

**preview**: http://media-clouds.com/ccc/#intro/buildings (it is the second page- open it in firefox to see it)

***The weird thing, it was working perfectly 3 days ago, very smooth and cool, all good! I even enhanced the page performance by technically making the draw jump to the last frame after 4 seconds (when the real image starts to fade in), like this:***

```
@keyframes draw {
   0% {
     stroke-dashoffset: -7200;
   }
7%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 }
   8%{
     stroke-dashoffset: 7200;
   }
 100%{
     stroke-dashoffset: 7200;
   }
  }
```

Suddenly today its crashing! and I kept tuning the keyframes rules desperately trying to solve the issue, even for 3 seconds duration it do crash!(and sometimes no!!!)

Hope you could help me on this

---

### Update

I did a workaround to make it work, in javascript I add class `.animate` which has the draw effect rules in CSS. then I remove the class just before the browser crash ( in my case it crash in the last frame of the animation)

and here is the code as a reference:

```
$(this).addClass("animate").delay(3000).queue(function(){

    $(this).removeClass("animate").dequeue();

});
```

This is just a workaround, not an effective solution that cure the bug from the roots.

Comment: if chrome crashes report it to chrome's bugtracker